# Unique Fields return detail view on form submit

Tags: python, django

When I submit my form I have a unique set to my fields, so I get this:

> Person with this Full name, Country and Date of birth already exists

How do I get it to send me to the exiting detail view?

```
class Person(models.Model):
full_name = models.CharField(
    max_length=50,
    )
country = models.ForeignKey(
    Country,
    default='FIXED',
    )

date_of_birth = models.DateField(
    null=True,
    )
def __unicode__(self):
    return self.full_name

class Meta:
    unique_together = (("full_name", "country", "date_of_birth"),)

@models.permalink
def get_absolute_url(self):
        return ("checker:detail", (), {
            "pk": self.pk
        })
```

Views.py

```
class PersonTest(CreateView):
    model = Person


class PersonTestDetail(DetailView):
    model = Person
```

Comment: What, when does "user" come into this? @DanielRoseman

Comment: Person, whatever. The point is that you are specifically using a view that creates a new one, and then complaining that you're getting uniqueness errors. Just don't create a new one.

Comment: But if it doesn't exist I want it to create the object? If I shouldn't use CreateView, what should I use? @DanielRoseman

Comment: OK, this is why you should always state your actual requirements up front. Your question was originally about filling in a form and going to a detail view; now you're asking about, what, some kind of create-or-update functionality? Rather than letting me guess what you are trying to do, you should edit the question and explain it in full.

Comment: "How do I get it to send me to the exiting detail view?"

Comment: How is that not clear? Maybe you should read the question @DanielRoseman

Comment: "create-or-update" No... Create or return the existing object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is my own soultion I came up with

```
class PersonTest(CreateView):
    model = Person

    def form_invalid(self, form):
        try:
            person = Person.objects.get(full_name=form.cleaned_data['full_name'], date_of_birth=form.cleaned_data['date_of_birth'], country=form.cleaned_data['country'])
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('checker:detail', kwargs={'pk': person.id}))
        except:
            return super(ModelFormMixin, self).form_invalid(form)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want redirect to DetailView existing object, while trying to save new object, you should override clean method in your ModelForm class, something like this:

```
class YourForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Person

    def clean(self):
        cleaned_data = self.cleaned_data

        full_name = cleaned_data.get("full_name")
        country = cleaned_data.get("country")
        date_of_birth = cleaned_data.get("date_of_birth")

        if Person.objects.filter(full_name=full_name, country=country, date_of_birth=date_of_birth).count() > 0:
            del cleaned_data["full_name"]
            del cleaned_data["country"]
            del cleaned_data["date_of_birth"]

            person_pk = Person.objects.get(full_name=full_name, country=country, date_of_birth=date_of_birth).pk

            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('checker:detail', args=[person_pk]))

        return cleaned_data
```

Then update your CreateView:

```
class PersonTest(CreateView):
    model = Person
    form_class = YourForm
```